# На Mac PyCharm не хочет со мной разговаривать)

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, text-to-speech, pyaudio, google-speech-recognition

Я очень начинающий питонист. Пытаюсь разобраться в уже готовом, работающем коде.

1. Вылезает ошибка: Open speech channel failed: -76
2. Но главное - он слышит меня, но сам фразы НЕ произносит. Что мне делать?)

Mac OS, пакеты необходимые через pip вроде бы все установлены. Наверное не видит устройство ВОСПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЯ звука?
Вот готовый код, который пытаюсь просто запустить у себя: https://pastebin.com/tybwCZxb

Вот пакеты, установленные в этом файле:
Пакеты:
PyAudio 0.2.11  0.2.11
SpeechRecognition   3.8.1   3.8.1
pip 20.1.1  20.1.1
setuptools  47.1.1  47.1.1

Скрин прилагаю:
[image: Осовной скрин]

Comment: запомни раз и навсегда, гоша дударь - зло!

Answer (score 1):

Для владельцев macOS предварительно выполнить - `pip install PyObjC`

[Источник](https://github.com/manchenkoff/skillbox-voice-assistant#%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pyobjc-........

Answer (score 0):

Это частая ошибка после обновлений, когда слетают настройки синтеза голоса в osx:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5468363

или

http://kellerfarm.com/this-much-i-know/

В настройках синтеза речи надо выбрать существующий голос и убедиться, что он работает.